# rails showing blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I need to implement a conditional search form .There are two tables named tweets and coordinates , but the output is showing a blank page  and I am stuck up with dis.
my coordinates_controller

```
class CoordinatesController < ApplicationController
  def home 
  end
 # def paramas(b)
  #  
   # @b = params[:show]
   # return @b

  end
 #def coor(latitude,longitude)
  # @latitude=0
   #@longitude=0
  #end

  def query
    @a=Coordinates.find("city=?", params[:show])
    if(params[:show]= a.city) then 
      latitude= a.latitude
      longitude=a.longitude
    end
    if(latitude=0 && longitude=0) then
      return  sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE 'params[:show]' order by id desc"
    else if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) 
           min_lat = latitude - 1.0
           max_lat = latitude + 1.0
           min_lng = longitude - 1.0
           max_lng =  longitude + 1.0
           return   sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE 'params[:show]') ) order by id desc"
         else
           return   sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%'"
         end    

    end
  end
```

My Tweets_controller
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

```
include CoordinatesHelper
  def search
    render 'tweets/search'
  end


  def index

   # include CoordinatesHelper
    sql=query
   @tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => @page, :per_page => @per_page )
    #render 'tweets/index'
  end
end
```

my view code  for the search button

```
<%=form_tag({controller: 'tweets', action:'index'},  method: "get") do %>
<%=label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
<%=text_field_tag(:text) %>
<%=label_tag(:show, "Show for:") %>
<%=text_field_tag(:show) %>
<%= submit_tag( "GO" ) %>
<% end %>
```

my  view code to display the results

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>

<ul>

  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>

</ul>
<% end %>
```

But for some reasons the output is showing an empty page tried editing several tymes but in vain. Anybody kindly help me wid dis, I am struggling wid dis from a long tym

Comment: Looks like `@tweets` is empty. Check the value of `@tweets` when you load the page.

Comment: if(params[:show]= a.city) then ... what is a , thinking it would be @a

Comment: @RobWagner can u pls tel me how to find out if it is empty? yhks in advance

Comment: @Debadatt its something like if the entered city is inside the table then the latitude and longitude variables must be set to  the latitude and longitude attributes of that particular city.

Answer (score 0):

In your query method, you wrote and finder method, but you have write table name there, not model name, finders works on Model name, write like this :

In your query method replace this :

```
@a=Coordinates.find("city=?", params[:show])
```

with this :

```
@a=Coordinate.find("city=?", params[:show])
```

because model name, always remain singular, unless you make changes any configuration. 
and I think, there is a problem with your params[:show] with this. Please paste your result of 'params[:show]'

Hope it will help. Thanks